# Can't run command using C-. keybinding with Evil

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I'm trying to use `racket-mode` for programming Racket.  One of the racket-mode commands is bound to <kbd>C-c C-.</kbd> (control c, control period).

However, whenever I try to press <kbd>C-c C-.</kbd>, it appears to get interpreted as <kbd>C-c .</kbd> (control c, period).

How can I go about debugging why this is happening?

My guess is that this is caused because I am using `evil`.  If I run `describe-key` and type <kbd>C-.</kbd>, a `*Help*` buffer is opened for the command `evil-repeat`, which is bound to <kbd>.</kbd>.

Is evil somehow ignoring the Control key whenever it sees <kbd>.</kbd>?  How can I tell it to not do this?

Comment: Are you using emacs in a terminal?

Comment: Yes!  I am using emacs in a terminal!  Maybe the terminal is eating my `Control` key?